# how do i set my screen for tablet?

Tags: android

this is my XML code below i make app for tablet how do i set my layout? is change  image button position when  moving from  portrait to landscape mode  (green color button)
and also so much space in between 4 image icon and playstore icon when in portrait how do i reduce this?? help me please this is my images https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7idp.jpg and  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyHYs.jpg  i want to show green button below header right side above 4 icons button and also reduce  gap in between 4 icon and googleplay store icon    how do i do this? is change is position when moving portrait to landscape  i make this for tablet 1024 into 600 resolution

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/home_bgg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="65.0dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />


    </FrameLayout>
      <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/btnSetting"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="10.0dip"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/power_on" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="center" >


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/btnCamera"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/home_btn_camera" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/btnHdr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/home_btn_padding"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnCamera"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/home_btn_hdr" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/btnBeautify"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btnCamera"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/home_btn_padding"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/home_btn_edit" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/btnCollage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/btnHdr"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/btnBeautify"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnBeautify"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/home_btn_collage" />
    </RelativeLayout>

   <RelativeLayout

           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0.0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
         android:gravity="center"
         >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/btnsearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:background="@null"
             android:gravity="center" 
             android:layout_centerInParent="true"

            android:src="@drawable/google_play"
             />
          <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/btnHot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
             android:gravity="right" 
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

            android:src="@drawable/footer_logoo"
             />



    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

 </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

put that green button on the same Framelayout with image view, and for the other 4 buttons, give an id for thr bottom google play relatiev layout and then **in the relative layout of four buttons** use this, android:layout_above="@+id/id_of_googleplay relative layout", and remove the layout_weights, and gravity, they are in linearlayout so gravity makes no sense since they are oriented consequently

Answer (score 0):

because answer is too long to fit in comment, i wrote it as a new answer
here you go

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/home_bgg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="65.0dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/btnSetting"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="10.0dip"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/power_on" />

    </FrameLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/play_layout" >


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/btnCamera"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/home_btn_camera" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/btnHdr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/home_btn_padding"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnCamera"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/home_btn_hdr" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/btnBeautify"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btnCamera"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/home_btn_padding"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/home_btn_edit" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/btnCollage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/btnHdr"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/btnBeautify"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnBeautify"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/home_btn_collage" />
    </RelativeLayout>

   <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/play_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/btnsearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:background="@null"
             android:gravity="center" 
             android:layout_centerInParent="true"

            android:src="@drawable/google_play"
             />
          <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/btnHot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
             android:gravity="right" 
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

            android:src="@drawable/footer_logoo"
             />



    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

 </FrameLayout>
```